# Applescript to rule "sent mailbox zero"?

Tags: email, applescript

According to [GTD](http://gettingthingsdone.com) and "[inbox zero](http://www.43folders.com/izero)" I also wanted a corresponding "sent mailbox zero" by applying a rule in Apple Mail. (Why? Please, see the end of this question.)

Now, here is a simple Applescript solution: `sortOut`. **How could it be more efficient?**

The workflow is simply this

1. Loop through all sent messages that was a reply to some other message.
2. Get the message id of the message the sent message was a reply to.
3. Locate the mailbox for this (prior) message.

Any suggestions how to solve step 3 more efficiently will be appreciated, e.g. locating a mailbox directly based on message id, without having to use the `message:` protocol and then open the message and preferably not to code something like `... (in every mailbox) whose message id is mID` which turns out to be rather slow.

```
tell application "Mail"
    set i to 0
    set mb1 to sent mailbox
    repeat with m in ((messages of mb1) whose all headers contains "In-Reply-To")
        set mID to content of header "In-Reply-To" of m
        set cmd to "open 'message:" & mID & "'"
        try
            do shell script cmd
            delay 1
            set s to the selection
            set m2 to item 1 of s
            set mb2 to mailbox of m2
            set mailbox of m to mb2
            close front window
            set i to i + 1
        end try
    end repeat

    if i ≠ 1 then
        set s to "s"
    else
        set s to ""
    end if

    set myMsg to (i & " message" & s & " moved successfully") as rich text
    display notification myMsg with title "SortOut" subtitle "Sorting complete"
end tell
```

*Some earlier discussions elsewhere indicate that some people may even wonder why I want this. My reason is simply that I like to have have all threads and conversations, concerning every project and deadline, collected together based on context.*

*When a project is finished I archive it as a completed entity for easy reference if I need to go back or follow up some things (e.g. when planning a yearly event, “Remember what I replied to this question last year?” That also means that all those conversations will have the same label in gmail.*

*So, instead of having almost 15000 sent emails in one mailbox, I now have them sorted into context based mailboxes—and the mailbox for sent messages is empty!*

BTW, the Alfred workflow Mail Actions by Pedro Lobo is simply amazing for filing mail. My script `sortOut` does the rest ;-)

*Sorry, Pedro, I didn't have enough reputation to post a link to your brilliant work.*

Comment: I just updated the code but the question still remains: How could be more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

I just updated the code but still could not locate the mailbox corresponding to a message id from the In-Reply-To header using Applescript (without the `message:`protocol).

```
tell application "Mail"
    set i to 0
    set mb1 to sent mailbox
    repeat with m in ((messages of mb1) whose all headers contains "In-Reply-To")
        set mID to content of header "In-Reply-To" of m
        set cmd to "open 'message:" & mID & "'"
        try
            do shell script cmd
            delay 1
            set s to the selection
            set m2 to last item of s
            set mb2 to mailbox of m2
            if name of mb2 does not contain "INBOX" then
                set mailbox of m to mb2
                close front window
                set i to i + 1
            end if
        end try
    end repeat

    if i ≠ 1 then
        set s to "s"
    else
        set s to ""
    end if

    set myMsg to (i & " message" & s & " moved successfully") as rich text
    display notification myMsg with title "SortOut" subtitle "Sorting complete"
    mb2
end tell
```